# MySQL search a text from two columns

Tags: mysql, regex

i have a table (tbl_world) which look like this

```
  id | first_name | last_name | age | class |
```

now i want to search the text which can be  anywhere in first_name or in last_name

i m using below mysql query

```
 "SELECT * FROM tbl_world WHERE REGEXP '".$word."' IN( first_name, last_name)";
```

where `$word`  is user input (means if i search 'hell' then 'hello' as well as 'wellhell' also returned in result)

above query display error,  please suggest me optimize method for search in mysql.

**addition question:** should i use LIKR or RLIKE?

Comment: It is imperative that the you escape, filter or bind `$word` to protect from SQL injection.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216324/avoiding-sql-injection-in-a-user-generated-sql-regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it with:

```
"SELECT * FROM tbl_world WHERE first_name REGEXP '" . $word .
    "' OR  last_name REGEXP '" . $word . "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 "SELECT * FROM tbl_world 
WHERE first_name LIKE  '%".$word."%' 
OR last_name LIKE  '%".$word."%'";
```

(Consider enabling fulltext search if you want to search for a string among multiple fields.)

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT * FROM tbl_world WHERE first_name LIKE '%'".$word."%' OR last_name LIKE '%".$word."%'"
```