# PHP & SQL: WHERE MATCH to look for two or more columns

Tags: php, mysql

I am having some difficulties looking for exact match in two or more columns using WHERE MATCH. Below script which I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE MATCH (_fristname) AGAINST ('$search') LIMIT 0, 2;
```

The code above is working perfectly,

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE MATCH (_lastname) AGAINST ('$search') LIMIT 0, 2;
```

The code above is working too,

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE MATCH (_firstname, _lastname) AGAINST ('$search') LIMIT 0, 2;
```

The code above is not working. I want to search for exact match in both columns

The code below is what I used to output in PHP:

```
$searched = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($searched)) {
   echo $info['_jobdescription'];
}
```

Comment: have you tried to combine them in another way? like `match(fname) against (search) OR match(lname) against (search)`?

Comment: Thank, it is working. However, it is not displaying the most relevant results.

Comment: use UNION. see this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529724/mysql-search-a-text-from-two-columns