# Which is the Best way to prvent SQL injection using PHP

Tags: php, sql, database

Now my query, SP  is breaking if i enter

> ssds ' " '  sdsds

or  just

> ' " '

this is for mainly search functionality.

Which will be the best way to avoid all possibilities.

eg: str_replace  or better ways.. write some function!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216324/avoiding-sql-injection-in-a-user-generated-sql-regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't mention which DBMS, so I'm assuming MySQL here.

The best way would be to use PDO and/or prepared statements.  The next best way would be to use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) if you are using the procedural API.

Comment: Can i use mysql_real_escape_string  for any other database like db2?  just for filtering

Comment: @zod - no, mysql_real_escape_string requires a connection to mysql to work.  There is another function, mysql_escape_string, that will work without a connection, but it's not as good as the "real" version, and I'm also not sure if it will escape the string properly for databases other than MySQL.

Comment: @zod: No. `mysql_real_escape_string` works only for MySQL. DB2 has `db2_escape_string`. In fact, each database engine provides its own escaping mechanism. PDO, on the other hand, escapes automatically no matter what.

Comment: Thanks Eric and netcoder for the information. Can we use prepared statements in Stored Procedure? Can you send any useful URLS which explains how this can be done? i will look into PDO. IS the PDO and PEAR are same or different?

Comment: @zod - here would be a good place to start:  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.apdv.php.doc/doc/t0023502.htm

Answer (score 1):

Check out **prepared statements** in the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html), in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), or [this article](http://mattbango.com/notebook/web-development/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/), before even starting to look at escaping.

It is just too easy to get escapes wrong!

Dw.

Answer (score 1):

Use a prepared statement to separate your logic (SQL) and your content (whatever your input is). You don't have to worry about all those escape things, you just tell your query that you're input is a string, not SQL code.
Guessing mysql:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php

quick example:

```
$stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO table VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", "your'''\\\input goes here");
$stmt->execute();
```