# SQL injection risk - allow REGEXP input

Tags: php, mysql, regex, sql-injection

I am considering allowing users to insert their own REGEXP pattern which will be used in a Mysql query. I am well aware of sql injection risks, and I know there is no way of passing the regexp pattern value as an argument to a prepared statement.

Is there a waterproof way to safely allow users to provide their own regexp pattern for in the sql query, or should I abandon this idea?

I am working with PHP, by the way, so I am basically asking if it is possible in PHP to make sure the pattern is valid, genuine and harmless.

Comment: "I know there is no way of passing the regexp pattern value as an argument to a prepared statement." Really? Why not? Works with LIKE patterns, right, so why not with regexp?

Comment: The regex can be a bound parameter. Where did you read otherwise?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Avoiding SQL injection in a user-generated SQL-regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216324/avoiding-sql-injection-in-a-user-generated-sql-regex)

Comment: Oh, am I mistaken about that? The last time I working with database systems, I did so with much more primitive database systems (front end web sqlite, google gears) and I know it's not possible for those.

Comment: There are a few problems: **1-** MySQL regex flavor is quite limited compared to the PCRE PHP flavor, so it's quite impossible to check if the regex provided is valid in mysql without testing it on mysql **2-** There is no "waterproof" solution except prepared statements against first order SQL injection since validating against a characterset is almost useless since there are several techniques to bypass them (obfuscate the query).

Comment: May I ask you why do you want to provide such "function" if you don't trust it's users ? You may just provide them a set of regexes defined in your PHP codebase that you wrote, that way you'll be sure that nothing can go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Good question! I experienced that in general users are not really 'educated' enough to enter 'real' regular expressions. The 'standard' user considers the asterisk already as being really complicated. Patterns like `/^([^[0-9]+\s[a-z]*)/i` are very rarely used by the 'average' user. You wll probably be better advised to provide the user with simpler meta-characters as wildcards. *Unless* you want to use the tool as an administrator tool ... for people who know what they are doing.

Comment: They are supposed to know what they are doing, so that is not the issue. The better they know what they are doing, the more concerned I should be about security.

Comment: Actually, going with pre-determined characters (assuming I understand this correctly) is the most secure way, making it much easier to sanitize user-inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this for mysql, but I've done something similar once for another dbms

what I did was:

1. determine what version/dialect of regex the db actually uses (there are several flavors. you could go for a restricted one like POSIX basic)
2. try to compile the regex in the application first (in my case it was java). if it throws an exception at this point, you know it's bad.
3. execute it on the db

additionally, you could:

- first execute it with a "sandbox" user (one using a dummy schema, with no rights to do anything dangerous) and see what happens.
- restrict it some more (validate it against a whitelist of allowed characters) e.g don't allow dangerous things like single quotes, semicolons, etc. I imagine php/mysql allows various encodings, so you'll have to deal with that too.

That being said I don't think you can completely remove the risk. edit: especially if you want to avoid denial-of-service attacks too.